# Is there a way to prevent Entity Framework to NEVER read entries where a property is a specific value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a software that has been in the works for a while, today our client decided we NOT delete any data but instead hide them. To do this, I plan to add an "isDeleted" property to all tables and change all methods for deletion to set this property to "true" instead.

Problem is, I have 1000 times more reading than deletion, I can have a User and try to read all Comments of this User by using entity relation, I have to either add a "Where(x => !x.isDeleted)" to every single read like this or if it is possible, opt out ALL data that has isDeleted as true from being read.

Is the latter possible in any way? If not, is there an alternative to writing "Where(x => !x.isDeleted)" a thousand times?

Comment: I know that Oracle has archiving options which makes rows invisible to applications. Does your database have a similar option?

Comment: There's nothing baked into EF6 as far as I remember. EF Core does have that built-in, but that's not much use for you I guess. However, all your data access code should be abstracted away right? Shouldn't be too hard to add all those `Where` clauses?

Comment: I think you should use repository design pattern from which you can specify isDeleted column for get method for all entities

Comment: In this scenario (perhaps wrongly), I tend to create a further method on my context, something like `public IQueryable<Entity> ActiveEntities => Entities.Where(t => !t.IsDeleted);`, therefore I can easily switch between getting just active, or getting all depending on my needs, and if my deletion logic ever changes (e.g. `from isDeleted` column, to `DeletedDate`) I only have to change it in one place. Yes, it will be a bit inconvenient changing a load of references from `Entities` to `ActiveEntities` in the first instance, but this only has to be done once.

Comment: EF core has global query filters which allow you do what you require. Could you create a .Net standard project and move your EF6 context over to EF Core in the new project and reference the original project to the new project?

Comment: You're asking about soft-deletes. If you search SO you'll find many questions about this. The functionality is baked-in in EF Core, there are various techniques in EF 6.x. Gareth's proposal is a perfectly good solution

Comment: Without changing a single bit in the client program, you can create a view in the database that filters the deleted ones from the table, and have your queries point at the view instead of the table.

Comment: @DavidG: Even if OP rewrites the where clauses, that doesn't change the behavior of the include clauses. I've tried tackling this issue before and it requires in-depth changes to EF's loading behavior, which is something that's not easily configurable using the (vanilla) EF interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at this problem before in the past and rolling your own solution is much more difficult than you'd initially think, mostly because it's really hard to change how `Include` statements load the related entities (EF doesn't really allow you to filter them).

But there is a library that can do it for you.

### Filtering the read results

It can be done quite easily using the [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters) library. (I am not in any way affiliated with the devs, I just really like their library)

The main readme actually has an example that fits your use case:

```
modelBuilder.Filter("IsDeleted", (ISoftDelete d) => d.IsDeleted, false);
```

Essentially, it will only return results `Where(d => !d.IsDeleted)`, which is exactly what you'd want. This filter is applied to all direct fetches *and* include statements, which means that those soft deleted entities are essentially non-existing as far as your domain is concerned.

This does assume that your entities all derive from a shared root which has the delete flag, which is something I'd advise you to do anyway.

### Soft-deleting the entities

It's also possible to convert hard deletes into soft deletes in your database context itself, which means that you don't need to rewrite your delete code to instead update the entity (which can be a cumbersome rewrite, and it's always possible that someone forgets it here and there).

You can override the `SaveChanges` (and `SaveChangesAsync`) behavior in your context class. This allows you to find all the entities that are going to be deleted, and gives you the option to convert this into an update statement while also raising the `IsDeleted` flag.

It also ensures that no one can forget to soft delete. Your developers can simply hard delete the entities (when handling the code), and the context will convert it for them.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ConvertHardDeleteToSoftDelete();

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ConvertHardDeleteToSoftDelete();

        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    private void ConvertHardDeleteToSoftDelete()
    {
        var deletedEntries = ChangeTracker
                                   .Entries<ISoftDelete>()
                                   .Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                                   .ToList();

        foreach (var entry in deletedEntries)
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            entry.IsDeleted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Combined with the dynamic filter suggestion above, this means that such a soft deleted entity will not appear again in your application, but it will still exist in the database.

Comment: +1, currently not at work so not able to try it for my own project, will accept answer if it works but I don't see why it wouldn't, seem perfectly applicable to my situation. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Tried this bit by bit at work by creating a table for testing, added "isDeleted" field to table with 5 entries where 1 has "isDeleted" as true, debugged the code and it even goes through "ConvertHardDeleteToSoftDelete()" method but it doesn't filter and still lists 5 entries from table and when I delete, it just deletes. Any idea why it may not be working? My DbContext is essentially same, only additional code is a "ToList()" and "RemoveRange()" in "Main()" to test

Comment: Problem seems to be with Interface I created, I just created an "interface ISoftDelete" that contains isDeleted property but I am assuming that is what is causing it not to work, but I couldn't find how ISoftDelete property should be

Comment: @TolgaAçış `ChangeTracker.Entries<ISoftDelete>()` gives you only the entries that implement the referenced type (and ignores all other entries), so you do have to make sure that you ask for a type which your entity classes actually implement (otherwise you get an empty list). You can fix this whichever way you like: use `Entries<MyEntityType>()` instead, or make sure your entity types implement `ISoftDelete` (or any other interface that would carry the `bool IsDeleted` flag - that's up to you to implement as you see fit). I advise you to take the latter option as it covers all entities at once